# eloquent javascript - chapter 4 weresquirrel's log

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, eloquent

so far, a great book and a huge boost to my javascript understanding. then comes this part

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
    return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
    var table = [0, 0, 0, 0]; // how does this work ?????
    for(var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
        var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
        if(hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
        if(entry.squirrel) index += 2;
        table[index] += 1;      
    }
return table;

}
```

there is a array JOURNAL of 90 length filled with 2 object properties each, with one of them beign array, other boolean (JOURNAL file http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/jacques_journal.js) which when i type tableFor('pizza', JOURNAL); he gives me this information bucket [76,9,4,1];

how does he traverse through those offsets, and find exactly a value through array method indexOf('something') if there is multiple instances of 'something'?

Comment: `traverse through those offsets` what offsets?

Comment: so, 76 of those journal entries have no pizza and squirrel == false, 9 have pizza with squirrel == false, 4 have squirrel == true, but no pizza, and one has pizza with squirrel == true - how did I do without looking at the external linked data?